# Strange margins in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I need a list of view scrolled horizontally, so i've put LinearLayout in HorizontalScrollView
and added elements to the LinearLayout. Everything is fine, but there is strange margins/padding(I don't know what it is)

This is the view fully scrolled to the left - first item is half aboard the parent

[image]

And this is the fully scrolled to the right one - strange padding on the right side

http://korniltsev.ru/m/gyazo/4d093939766fe.png

THis is my xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_payment_system_item"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
    </FrameLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seems like the horizontalScrollview or its parent defined some sort of padding/margin.

Comment: OMFG! I just mentioned the padding on the right side changes in time!!

Comment: Try setting the gravity in HorizontalScrollView to center?

Comment: @aswin-kumar there is no souch attribute in HSView

Answer (score 4):

Ok so this behavior is an android bug. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20088

Answer (score 0):

You might try the strategy in the code, to judge the content width of HScroller and compare with the device/container width:

1. if the content is wider than the container: set the gravity of the content as "left" value
2. if the content is thinner than the container: set the gravity of the content as "center" value

I think this is just a UX design issue of the requirement, the strategy works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your HorizontalScrollView.

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```